# Problem in python with multiprocessing.Manager().list()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABoac.jpg)

In this program, I would like to use the `multiprocessing.Manager().list()` to share a list in two processing.
the purpose for this program is for quantitative trade.

I use the processing test1 to subscribe code information, while the processing test2 to subscribe the sector information, and then I would like to get the sector information from processing test2 with a `multiprocessing.Manager().list() sector_list`.

But I can't get the changed sector_list in test1 even if it was changed in test1 all the time.

Comment: no pictures please. add the code as text to your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.